# Setting SUN Java environment on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, java

I just installed Ubuntu 10.04 on my personal laptop and wanted to set up my development environment on this.

I see that when i run the command

**Installed SUN JDK through synaptic package manager** and executed this command:

> sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-6-sun

But when i run the command `which java`

the output displayed is

> /usr/bin/java

How do i make sure that it is Sun JDK and not OpenJDK (which was installed in ubuntu by default)

My only concern is :

> **I want only SUN JDK to be used for all purposes. I do not want
>   OpenJDK..**

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: use "java -version" to know the version and other details about the java your are running.

Comment: The output of the command : `java -version` is `ram@ram-laptop:~$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_22"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 17.1-b03, mixed mode)`

Comment: it's the hotspot java which means it's by oracle/Sun http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can config the used JavaVM with:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Or you just remove all open-jdk packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can see java version via

```
java -version
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong...

I think you can run `echo $PATH` and it'd give you the list of directories in exact order they're supposed to be scanned when the system trying to run the command.

So, I can see several options to resolve:

1. If your default java version is wrong, just remove it and install the correct one.
2. If you need several versions of java by any reason, you can:

   1. modify your PATH environment making your new java path with higher priority. I.g.:

      ```
      export PATH=/usr/java_xyz/bin:$PATH
      ```
   2. Set your JAVA_HOME environment pointing to new java and make your calls with something like:

      ```
      $JAVA_HOME/bin/java blablabla.class
      ```